# Why doesn't Overleaf show the glossary?

Tags: glossaries, overleaf

I have been working on my thesis that has a glossary and acronym part and at first it showed them but suddenly it has disappeared.
I did a lot of tests on new documents but almost none of them work for me, only one of them worked for me. I don't know why it works, because if I make a copy of the document as it is, it doesn't show me the glossary in the copy and in the original it does. Which is weird because it's literally an exact copy of the same code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{Latex/Classes/PhDthesisPSnPDF}

\usepackage{blindtext}         %  For dummy text.
% The \blindtext or \Blindtext commands throughout this template generate dummy text to fill the template out.

\include{Latex/Comands}           % Special commands written by the author

\usepackage{setspace}

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                  Information of the Student                                
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{Study on something really important}
\author{Author}       
\degree{Degree}% Physics
\director{Director}% Thesis director
\degreedate{Year}% Year of the dissertation
\lugar{Place}% Place of the dissertation
\portadatrue

% ----------------------------- Datos del jurado
\student{Paternal last name\\ Maternal Last name\\ Names\\ Telefon number\\ Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México\\ Facultad de Ciencias\\ Física\\ Student Number}
\secretario{Dr \\ Secretary (thesis director) \\ Last name \\ Last name}
\presidente{Dr \\ President \\ Last name \\ Last name}
\vocal{Dr \\ Vocal \\ Last name \\ Last name}
\supuno{Dr \\ substitute 1 \\ Last name \\ Last name}
\supdos{Dr \\ Substitute 2 \\ Last name \\ Last name}
\pags{pages}

\keywords{tesis,autor,tutor,etc}            % For metadata 
\subject{tema_1,tema_2}                     % Sebjucts for metadata


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
%                                   COVER                                   
%-----------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article} %Although the documentclass is repeated, the code compiles, only %sometimes it shows the glossary, other times it doesn't
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
        name=latex,
        description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=mathematics,
        description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
        name=formula,
        description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
%--------------------------
\begin{document}
%
\maketitle                                  
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                   FRONT MATTER                                
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\frontmatter

\include{0-1-Acknowledgments/1-Acknowledgments}          
\include{0-2-Declaration/1-Declaration}
\include{0-3-Quote/1-Quote}                  
\include{0-4-Resumen/1-Resumen}       

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                INDICES                                    |
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % organisational level that receives a numbers
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    % print table of contents for level 3

\tableofcontents            % Print main index

%: ----------------------- list of figures/tables ------------------------
%\listoffigures              % Genera el ínidce de figuras, comentar línea si no se usa
%\listoftables               % Genera índice de tablas, comentar línea si no se usa


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                MAIN MATTER                                   %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% the main text starts here with the introduction, 1st chapter,...
\mainmatter

\def\baselinestretch{1}                   % Line spacing

\input{0-5-Introduccion/1-Motivation-Structure}            
\input{1-Theory/1-Basics}
    \input{1-Theory/2-Something_more_specific}
\input{2-Results/1-Something}
\input{3-Conclusions/1-Conclusions}        

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                               References                                   |
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\appendix
\input{5-Apendices/1-Something_extra.tex}  

\setlength\bibitemsep{.1\itemsep}
\printbibliography

\printindex
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                              Appendix                                   |
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\printglossary

           
\end{document}
```

As it is a thesis, the chapters are separated in `.tex` files but this is the part where I include the glossary.

Do you have any idea why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with **only** the part of the code that you had shown in the question? If not, I'm afraid there's not much we can do. Try the LaTeX support at overleaf?

Comment: never use `\include`  in  the preamble `\include{Latex/Comands}` should be `\input`  but as we do not have that file we can not use your example

Answer (score 1):

From the section `Compiling the glossary` in Overleaf's  [`Glossaries`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries#Terms_and_Acronyms) manual:

> To compile a document that contains a glossary in Overleaf you don't have to do anything special, but if you add new terms to the glossary once you compiled it, make sure to click on Clear cached files first under logs option).